# Add parameter to url

Tags: ruby, url, parameters

I have a url (e.g. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=og9B3BEnBHo) and I'd like to add a parameter to it (wmode=opaque) so that its:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=og9B3BEnBHo&wmode=opaque

Can anyone tell me which function to use to make this work?

Comment: We would need a little more information to be able to help out. ie code. With the current I'd say do "uri + 'wmode=opaque' and that would give you the correct string. Are you using net/http or another library?

Comment: I'd like to make sure that it's join properly (it's user input). note: 'http://www.youtube.com/watch' + 'wmode=opaque' should become 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?wmode=opaque'

Comment: If you have the params as a `Hash`, try `to_query`. It's part of `ActiveSupport` so you might also have to require that. But it works great for us.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

```
require 'uri'

uri =  URI.parse("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=og9B3BEnBHo")
uri.query = [uri.query, "wmode=opaque"].compact.join('&') 
puts uri.to_s

#edit Since 1.9.2 there are methods added to the URI module

uri =  URI.parse("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=og9B3BEnBHo")
new_query_ar = URI.decode_www_form(String(uri.query)) << ["wmode", "opaque"]
uri.query = URI.encode_www_form(new_query_ar)
puts uri.to_s
```

(The call to `String` ensures that this also works in the case when the original URI does not have a query string)

Comment: `uri.query` returns `nil` if the URL has not any param and the `URI.decode_www_form(nil)` breaks.

Comment: `new_query_ar = URI.decode_www_form(uri.query || []) << ["wmode", "opaque"]` if you run into the nil issue

Comment: Note; decode requires a string rather than an array, so

`new_query_ar = URI.decode_www_form(uri.query || '') << ["wmode", "opaque"]`

Comment: This answer is outdated. Use `URI.encode_www_form({wmode: "opaque"})` instead.

Answer (score 24):

As Ruby has evolved over the years the answer differs between versions.

## After 1.9.2

Ruby 1.9.2 saw `decode_www_form` and `encode_www_form` added to the URI module, making encoding parameters easier.

```
require 'uri'

uri = URI.parse("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=og9B3BEnBHo")
new_query_ar = URI.decode_www_form(uri.query || '') << ["wmode", "opaque"]
uri.query = URI.encode_www_form(new_query_ar)
puts uri.to_s
```

#### Explanation

[`URI.decode_www_form`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html#method-c-decode_www_form) breaks a string of query parameters (`uri.query`) into a nested array of parameters (`[["v", "og9B3BEnBHo"]]`)

`uri.query || ''` supplies either the query string of the uri, or if it does not exist, an empty string. This prevents `decode_www_form` from running into an error if `uri.query` is `nil`.

`<< ["wmode", "opaque"]` adds another element to the array of query parameters. You may add more by further extending `new_query_ar`: `new_query_ar << ["fullscreen", "1"]`

[`URI.encode_www_form`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html#method-c-encode_www_form) encodes the nested array new query parameters into a string.

## Before 1.9.2

```
require 'uri'

uri = URI.parse("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=og9B3BEnBHo")
uri.query = [uri.query, "wmode=opaque"].compact.join('&') 
puts uri.to_s
```

#### Explanation

`[uri.query, "wmode=opaque"]` is an array of all the eventual query parameters. You may add more by extending the array: `[uri.query, "wmode=opaque", "fullscreen=1"]` or by adding to the final element: `"wmode=opaque&fullscreen=1"`

[`compact`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/Array.html#method-i-compact) removes `nil` elements from an array, thus it removes `uri.query` if there is not an existing query parameter.

[`join`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/Array.html#method-i-join), finally, joins them into a query string.

Answer (score 12):

Since you may have multiple query parameters you want to add and not just one, here's a version that lets you append as many params as you want by simply passing in a hash ... Plus a Hash seems like a more natural way to pass in `params` anyway, even if you're only adding one param.

```
  require 'uri'
  def add_params(url, params = {})
    uri = URI(url)
    params    = Hash[URI.decode_www_form(uri.query || '')].merge(params)
    uri.query =      URI.encode_www_form(params)
    uri.to_s
  end
```

Examples:

```
pry(main)> helper.add_params("http://example.com", b: 2)
=> "http://example.com?b=2"

pry(main)> helper.add_params("http://example.com?a=1", b: 2, c: 3)
=> "http://example.com?a=1&b=2&c=3"

pry(main)> helper.add_params("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=og9B3BEnBHo", wmode: 'opaque')
=> "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=og9B3BEnBHo&wmode=opaque"
```

Answer (score 10):

Another option is to use the **Addressable gem**

> https://github.com/sporkmonger/addressable

Once you include Addressable in your project all you will have to do is:

```
url = Addressable::URI.parse('http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=og9B3BEnBHo')
url.query_values = (url.query_values || {}).merge(wmode:"opaque")
```

Comment: related problem with addressable https://github.com/sporkmonger/addressable/issues/334

Answer (score 0):

In recent versions of the URI module, you can simply do:

```rb
original_uri = 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=og9B3BEnBHo'
append_params = { 'wmode': 'opaque' }

uri = URI.parse(original_uri)
params = URI.decode_www_form(uri.query || '') + append_params.to_a
uri.query = URI.encode_www_form(params)
puts uri.to_s
```